# iframe does not show correct only on firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Below is my code....

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('pltc');
iframe.contentWindow.document.open('text/htmlreplace');
iframe.contentWindow.document.write("<input type='checkbox'/>");
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
```

On Chrome browser, I will get a checkbox on screen.
But in firefox, i will get plain html text on screen.

```
<input type='checkbox'/>
```

Any reason why this happened?

Comment: When you call *document.open* you are clearing the entire document.  Try writing a valid document, including doctype. BTW, [*open*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-72161170) does not take any parameters. Probably not harmful, just pointless.

Comment: Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different compilation in different browsers when you called open.

In chrome, it helps you to inject html code into the iframe before rendering.
It is similar to js - document.write , which is exactly you want in the code.

In firefox, it helps you to inject html code into iframe after rendering, probably js - body.innerHTML

I suggest removing the open command and see if the content work in your way.

To be honest, there should not be such different, are you using SSL or https// in your web?